# MySQL WHERE timestamp >= SUBDATE(MAX(timestamp), INTERVAL 5 DAY)

Tags: mysql, date

What's the best way to express this in one SQL query?

"Select a few random items that fall within x days of the newest item in the table."

I tried the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
HAVING `timestamp` >= SUBDATE(MAX(`timestamp`), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

But this only gives me a single result, not 10. `WHERE` instead of `HAVING` doesn't cut it because of the use of `MAX()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want your `MAX` statement in a sub-query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE `timestamp` >= SUBDATE((SELECT MAX(`timestamp`) FROM table), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: D'oh, so obvious. I hoped for something without the need for a subquery for my DAO, but with a bit of trickery it works fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
where `timestamp` >= (select SUBDATE(MAX(`timestamp`), INTERVAL 5 DAY) from table )
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10;
```